# CORS request firing without sending form data on window.onbeforeunload event in IE9

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer, cors

I've got a pretty simple function which is designed to grab the form data and send it via a CORS request.  Basically it looks like this...

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    formData = getFormData();   
    logAbandonment(formData);
    // return formData;
    // alert(formData);
}

function logAbandonment(formData)
{
    if(!cors_request) {
        cors_request = true;
    } else {
        return;
    }

    var url = 'http://mydomain.lan/sub/index.php';
    var xhr = createCORSRequest('POST', url);
    if (!xhr) {
        console.log('Error:  CORS not supported.');
    }

    xhr.send(formData);
}

function createCORSRequest(method, url) 
{
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    if ("withCredentials" in xhr) {

        // Check if the XMLHttpRequest object has a "withCredentials" property.
        // "withCredentials" only exists on XMLHTTPRequest2 objects.
        xhr.open(method, url, true);
    } else if (typeof XDomainRequest != "undefined") {

        // Otherwise, check if XDomainRequest.
        // XDomainRequest only exists in IE, and is IE's way of making CORS requests.
        xhr = new XDomainRequest();
        xhr.open(method, url);
        xhr.onprogress = function () { };
        xhr.ontimeout = function () { };
        xhr.onerror = function () { };
        xhr.onload = function() { };
    } else {

        // Otherwise, CORS is not supported by the browser.
        xhr = null;

    }

    return xhr;
}

function getFormData()
{
    if(typeof FormData == 'undefined') {
        return serialize(document.getElementById('AppForm'));
    } else {
        return new FormData(document.getElementById('AppForm'));
    }
}
```

Because this is IE9 I am working with, I am using the XDomainRequest javascript object.

It is successfully firing the ajax request, but here is where I am having a problem.  It is firing it without sending the formData unless I uncomment either of the return or alert lines, in which case it works perfectly.  When I do that, I can see the correct data it is supposed to be saying in the alert.

Another thing I noticed is this only happens when I either close the browser or close the tab.  If I refresh the page, it works exactly like I want it to.

I thought maybe IE9 had some weird method of destroying the dom before the request was finished going out, but unfortunately, I can't figure out a way to set this to async false on XDomainRequest.

I've also tried setting a timeout, but that seems to break it completely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not an answer as much as a work-around, but I found this works perfectly when appending the query string onto the end of the url when calling xdr's open method.